# Get private subnet ids using Pulumi

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, pulumi, infrastructure-as-code

I am trying to create a new EKS cluster using Pulumi. In one of the steps, I need to use the private subnet ids.
When I try to get the ids using VPCID, it gives the error

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
index.ts(9,2): error TS2322: Type 'Output<string>' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

This is what I am trying to do

```
import * as pulumi from "@pulumi/pulumi";
import * as awsx from "@pulumi/awsx";
import * as eks from "@pulumi/eks";
import * as k8s from "@pulumi/kubernetes";
import * as aws from "@pulumi/aws";

const vpc = aws.ec2.Vpc.get('ais-name', 'vpc-er33332');
const privateSubnet = aws.ec2.getSubnetIds({
    vpcId: vpc.id,
});
```

AM I doing this wrong, or is there any other way to do this?
Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using apply on the `vpc.id`:

```js
const vpc = aws.ec2.Vpc.get('ais-name', 'vpc-er33332');

const privateSubnet = vpc.id.apply(
    vpcId => aws.ec2.getSubnetIds({
        vpcId: vpcId,
    })
);
```

Comment: Thank you @Maciej Raszplewicz.  I hadn’t considered that approach